# Remove name from in-text citation using biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-chicago

I'm using biblatex-chicago to write an exam. We are to follow a version of Chicago-style citations with footnotes, and only the superscript number in-text. When I use `\textcite[test]`, however, it compiles to

> Smith<sup>1</sup>

Instead of what I would want, which is:

> <sup>1</sup>

This a simplified version of my .tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{exam.bib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Statement of fact \textcite{test}

\end{document}
```

And here is the .bib:

```
@book{test,
        author = "Smith, Jake",
        title = "The Book of Testification",
        year = "1997",
        publisher = "Books Publishing LLC",
        }
```

How would I go about changing this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please -- as usual here -- show us a small, complilable tex code building your bibliography and please add also the used bib entry to your question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manual `\textcite`does the following:

> In the main text, they will provide an author’s name(s), followed
>   immediately by a foot- or endnote which contains the full (or short)
>   reference, following the usual rules.

If you need the only a footnote, you should use `\footcite` (or `\autocite`) instead.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{exam.bib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Statement of fact \autocite{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]